# Sorting in Django PostgreSQL is too slow

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have two Django models joined using a one-to-one link. Django generated this query for sorting and limit (PER_PAGE=20) objects in ChangeList:

```
SELECT
    "test_model_object"."id", 
    "test_model_object"."sorting_field_asc", 
    "test_model_object"."sorting_field_desc", 
    ... about fifteen fields ...
    "test_model_one_to_one_element"."id", 
    "test_model_one_to_one_element"."number"

FROM "test_model_object" 

INNER JOIN "test_model_one_to_one_element" 
    ON ("test_model_object"."test_model_one_to_one_element_id" = "test_model_one_to_one_element"."id") 

ORDER BY "test_model_object"."sorting_field_asc" ASC, "test_model_object"."sorting_field_desc" DESC LIMIT 20;
```

But execution is very slow in PostgreSQL for 1.5 million objects (about six second). I assumed uuid introduced some unwanted adjustments to sorting process, but test model with int indexes shows that's not it. What are some solution (maybe postgres settings) to speed up this Django PostgreSQL query?

Comment: Please add the Django ORM query that produces this SQL.

Comment: Are `sorting_field_asc` and `sorting_field_desc` indexed together? If not, that will certainly slow down your query.

Comment: I can't predict which fields will be sorted in advance. And it can be more than 2 (of course in different directions - ASC and DESC).

Answer (score 0):

What indexes have you created on the PostgreSQL table?

> execution is very slow in PostgreSQL for 1.5 million objects

That is to be expected on millions of records, yes.

This is only a problem if you need the operation to be fast. PostgreSQL and Django can't tell which operations you want to be fast, so by default no indexes are created.

So, because you've asked the question, we assume you would rather have that operation be faster. One way is to trade speed when writing records, to get speed when querying them.

You can [create an index on particular fields](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html), as a way of trading some slower write operations for faster query operations. The [index will be used also when sorting with `ORDER BY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-ordering.html).

If it's as simple as wanting to create an index on one field of your Django model, the [`db_index` field option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#db-index) specifies that.